# C++11 Lambda Passing with Capture

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to pass a lambda function with capture [&]. What is the correct declaration for a variable storing a capturing lambda? **[f2 below]**

```
// Non-capturing
void (*f1)() = [](){   }; // Works

// All by reference
void (*f2)() = [&](){  }; // Syntax Error
```

Comment: auto f = [&](){...} ?

Comment: Lambdas with captures cannot be converted to function pointers.

Comment: Note you are not trying to pass a lambda function by reference.

Comment: bad phrasing. I meant enabling reference in the lambda ["&" capture mode]

Comment: auto wont work in cases where I need the type. Ex: std::vector<auto> wont do. In the case of *non-capturing*, std::vector<void (*)()> will work.

Comment: @RandomClown: If you need a common type for lambdas with or without captures, use `std::function<void()>`. That uses type erasure to store any function object with that signature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ Standard, section § 5.1.2 / 6 : [expr.prim.lambda]

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression **with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function** with C ++ language linkage (7.5) having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator

Since your lambda has a capture (a default one : `[&]`), there is no conversion operator to a pointer to function.

---

Alternatively, you can use `std::function<>` to wrap your lambda :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int i = 42;  
  std::function<void(void)> f = [&](){ std::cout << i; };
  f();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was too wordy for me to understand on my own.

Comment: Thank you for this